# Asymptotic behaviour of brownian motion

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a brownian motion, i want to show that 
$$\frac{B_t}{t^p} \xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{a.s.} 0, $$
for all $p>\frac{1}{2}$.

I was told to use that

$$X_t = \frac{B_t^2 - t}{(t+1)^{2p}} \xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{a.s.} 0,$$

which i have proven already, but i can't see how $X_t \to 0 \, a.s.$ implies the first claim. Can someone give me a hint on how those two are related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p>1/2$ then $\frac{t}{(t+1)^{2p}} \to 0$. Combined with $X_t \to 0$, this implies $X_t + \frac{t}{(t+1)^{2p}} \to 0$.
But $$X_t + \frac{t}{(t+1)^{2p}} = \frac{B_t^2}{(t+1)^{2p}} = \left(\frac{B_t}{(t+1)^p}\right)^2 \to 0.$$
It follows that
$$
\frac{B_t}{(t+1)^p} \to 0
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{B_t}{t^p} = \frac{B_t}{(t+1)^p} \frac{(t+1)^p}{t^p} \to 0 \cdot 1 = 0
$$